# Getting no response for rails Coffeescript "Alert" for a link_to

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

I am new to rails and coffee however, I simply attempting to get an alert when a link is clicked! What happens instead is nothing. It turns the link_to into a dead link

My Controller.rb

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def new
@post = Post.new
 respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.xml { render :xml => @post.to_xml }
    end
end

def create
    @post = Post.create!(params[:post])
    format.html
    format.js
    redirect_to post_url
end


def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title,:body)
end
```

My index,html.erb looks like this

```
<%= link_to 'New', post_new_url, id: "go", :remote => true %>
```

and my post.coffee just has this code in it

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $("#go").click ->
     alert "Clicked!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. Apparent my code was bad.

```
$(document).on "click", "#go", ->
  alert "page has loaded!"
```